# Is there a word similar to "in depth" but for width (in width)?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For instance, there are different aspects of a topic. When you study "in width", you try to understand these different aspects just enough. Then, you may want to study one aspect in depth to fully understand this aspect. Is there a word with the "in width" meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From WordNet (r) 3.0 (2006):

```
  breadth
      n 1: the capacity to understand a broad range of topics; "a
           teacher must have a breadth of knowledge of the subject";
           "a man distinguished by the largeness and scope of his
           views" [syn: {breadth}, {comprehensiveness}, {largeness}]
      2: the extent of something from side to side [syn: {width},
         {breadth}]
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an idiom that refers to broad but shallow knowledge of a subject: **a mile wide, an inch deep**.

For example, if you can say "Thanks" in 15 different languages, your knowledge is broad, but it's "an inch deep".

Perhaps in your case you could say something along the lines of:

> I covered all these topics **a mile wide and an inch deep**. But I have studied some aspects in depth.